# Does the iOS AASA file need to sit on a secure connection? (HTTPS)?

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links, aasa

I'm trying to set up a universal link between a site and my app, but I realized that my site is on a non-secured connection (HTTP). If I want to have a universal link to my app, does the AASA request need to be on a secured connection (HTTPS)?

I have found some information about it but it isn't from the apple docs. A conformation about it would be great appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does require HTTPS [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) says:

> To protect users’ privacy and security, you should not use HTTP when
>   you need to transport data; instead, use a secure transport protocol
>   such as HTTPS.

Your can validate your AASA file using [this tool](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

> Upload the apple-app-site-association file to your **HTTPS** web server.

(emphasis mine)